# How to create a record in the database base on email received to my site?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, smtp

I have Laravel web application for my portfolio.
https://www.bunlongheng.com

Under the portfolio section, you will see this

[image]

Right now, I have a CRUD for admin only to create them, but a thought come to my mind ...

I would like to create this automated email to just email myself to create a new record to the database.

Example

Anyone email to : `portfolio@bunlongheng.com`

Subject: Title of portfolio
Body:

1. Task 1
2. Task 2
3. Task 3

With attachments : 2 images (example)

Goal:

I want to accept and parse that email, and create a new portfolio record

- Subject = Title
- Body = Description
- Attachments = Portfolio Images

[image]

How do I start ?

Comment: I would figure out where email is stored on my server first. Then see what I could do on periodically parsing it to do the "automation" tasks.

Comment: Depending on where/how the emails are hosted, they might have some API for it (like gmail has and API). If they don't, you need to read up on IMAP (there is a php extension for it). Then you can set up a cron job that checks for new emails using IMAP, parse them and create the records you need. It's way too broad for us to be able to give you a more detailed answer. But to be honest, I don't see why emailing the info would be easier than filling it out directly in the admin though. It's a lot of work for not much gain, imho.

Answer (score 2):

This is a too-large topic for a Stack Overflow answer.

Some starting places:

1. You need a mailbox accessible via [IMAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Message_Access_Protocol) or [POP3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_Office_Protocol).  (SMTP is for outbound messages. You could implement an SMTP *server* to handle incoming messages, but doing that correctly is a really vast programming and network engineering job and not worth the trouble.)

   **EDIT** You need to create that emailbox on some email server; it doesn't matter which one.  You can use gmail or outlook or your own domain's email. You could make `myappinbox@code-8.com` (if `code-8.com` is your domain obvs) or `someRandomThingOrOther@gmail.com`. Then you rig your software to talk to your service's IMAP or POP3 service. If it's a commercial service you can ask them to provide the IMAP or POP3 connection details. (It's a normal thing; they probably have a help page on it.)

   One little trick that may help you.  If the mailbox is `inbox@code-8.com`  you can send messages to `inbox+tag@code-8.com` and `inbox+anotherTag@code-8.com`, putting whatever you want after the `+`, and they all go to the same mailbox. So you can set up categories of incoming simply by telling different senders to send to mailboxes with different tags.
2. You need a php program that will poll (visit) that mailbox looking for new mail every so often. The way incoming email works, you need to pull it from a mailbox.
3. Your php program should use the [php IMAP / POP3 APIs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php). The API is called IMAP, but it handles both protocols.
4. It will use those APIs to fetch and decode the messages.
5. Then you can write php code to parse the format you expect inside the messages and handle it the way you want.

There are also some free open-source Laravel packages, [like this one](https://beyondco.de/docs/laravel-mailbox/getting-started/introduction), to do this task. It may be best to use one of those. Getting IMAP or POP3 code exactly right is tricky, especially in the area of deleting incoming messages when you're done with them. You'll take on a messy testing burden if you do it yourself. (Ask me how I know that sometime.)

Comment: Laravel Mailbox seems to be best for me... I wasn't sure what would be the email tp semd to after installing it. Will it be email@my-domain.com ?  I don't see it in the doc anywhere;

Comment: Please see my edit.